# Coupling class-D output to audio input of another device

Tags: audio, output, input, class-d

I have a [MAX98357](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max98357a-max98357b.pdf) with a class-D output stage that I want to use as the audio input to another device.

The other device has a high-impedance (around 2.2 kΩ) input and ground connection.

I was thinking of using an audio transformer across the class-D output and a pot between the output of the transformer and ground to feed the input.

Is this my best option or are there better solutions?

Comment: Best in which regard? There may be better solutions depending on what are your limits regarding price, size, availability, sound quality etc. Can you e.g just use an op-amp?

Comment: Does another device accept differential or single-ended audio input? Better if you can put a link to its datasheet, though.

Comment: The input is single ended to an ICOM IC-A210E transceiver aux audio input. Audio quality isn´t too important, it is intended to feed audio to headphones via the radio during flight so a noisy environment.

Answer (score 1):

> *I was thinking of using an audio transformer across the class-D output
> and a pot between the output of the transformer and ground to feed the
> input. Is this my best option or are there better solutions?*

I would say so. From the data sheet you can see that the output switches on both output pins: -

[image]

And, this means that to avoid common-mode-rejection of the high frequency PWM on both output pins, a transformer is probably the best candidate.

I think you would be very disappointed with a differential amplifier on this particular occasion.

Comment: This was my conclusion. I just thought I´d ask in case there was a better way but I couldn´t think of one myself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be about this simple:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fReavc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Might need to to add an RC low-pass filter to kill any audible switching noise.

Choose R1 to represent the load that the amp would normally expect to be there (8 ohm speaker?). Choose R4 to attenuate the signal enough so that when the gain pot is set to max, and the volume is set to max, that you don't overdrive/overload the headphone amp. This will depend on max peak-to-peak volts the headphone amp will accept.

UPDATE: Just looked at the datasheet and realized this wasn't a single-ended output. Unless both devices are floating with respect to one another, you're going to need to transformer-couple the output of the MAX98357.

Comment: Yes, it was not a single ended output, it was mentioned in the question too. And no, transformer coupling is not the only option.

Comment: @Justme I've considered cap coupling the two stages, but then you have to worry about losing low-end frequency response. How else would you do it if you don't use a transformer?